# Why Swift library uses "enum CommandLine" instead of "struct CommandLine"?

Tags: swift, struct, enums

The Swift standard library declares `CommandLine` as an enum.

```
/// Command-line arguments for the current process.
public enum CommandLine {

    /// Access to the raw argc value from C.
    public static var argc: Int32 { get }

    /// Access to the raw argv value from C. Accessing the argument vector
    /// through this pointer is unsafe.
    public static var unsafeArgv: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?> { get }

    /// Access to the swift arguments, also use lazy initialization of static
    /// properties to safely initialize the swift arguments.
    public static var arguments: [String]
}
```

The purpose of the API could very well be achieved by declaring `CommandLine` as a struct.
**Any specific reason why it is declared as an enum instead of a struct?**

Comment: This is where it was changed from struct to enum: https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/03021eccb3439ad89efeb462a9702b1e7bb5595c. (Later “Process“ was renamed to “CommandLine“.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, based on some research, I found this:

**The advantage of using a case-less enumeration is that it can't accidentally be instantiated and works as a pure namespace.** (Ref: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#constants)

I believe this could possibly be one of the reasons.

Comment: That's the only reason and it's the correct answer.